# How to copy data from rest api using oauth to azure blob storage as json using adf

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I have difficulties creating an ADF pipeline that pulls data from a REST API using oAuth and writes it to azure blob storage in JSON format. I am a python developer and relatively new to adf. I will explain in more detail below.

1. I need to obtain an access token by posting a request to the token endpoint. This step works fine.
   [image]
2. I need to pull the data from the API using a GET request in a copy activity. Also I need to include pagination. Is there something wrong on the way I define the pagination rules? "@odata.nextLink" is full description of the json key; is this correctly spelled in the value section?
   [image]
3. I need to copy the data to a blob storage in json format. I created the sink dataset.

[image]

4. Upon running the pipeline it asks for 2 pipeline parameters, what am I supposed to write here?

[image]

5. I get the following error, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: As error shows, your source data is invalid JSON format.Please check that.

Comment: I ran the script in Python where it runs perfectly. Where can I check the JSON? Can’t run the pipeline due to the error

Comment: You can use postman.